# Android glow effect like SEGA logo

Tags: android, animation, glow

I want to apply a `glow` effect to some `ImageViews`. I don't want an outter glow, I want an effect like the SEGA logo:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hpgwsXT6NgU

I mean, I have my `ImageView` like it is, and then I want a "light ray" to go from the left-bottom corner to the right-top corner. **This effect has to be independent from the `image`**, since I'll have a lot of different images and I don't want to create several images for each one with the glow effect on it.

Right now I created a "light ray" image using photoshop (a 1 pixel line with an outer glow and transparent background) and I translate it over my ImageView. It's similar to what I want, but the effect is a bit stiff, I don't like the way it is.

Is there any better way to do it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

An OpenGL solution has the potential to result in great quality.  There are likely simpler solutions out there.

Check out this [Android + OpenGL ES 2.0 "hello world"](https://code.google.com/p/gdc2011-android-opengl/)